# How to reset the look of .htm file icon?

Tags: windows-8, windows-explorer, windows-8.1, icons, file-association

My htm/html files saved on the desktop in Windows 8 looked like this:

[image]

Now when I upgraded to Windows 8.1 they look like this:

[image]

How can I return their previous look?

PS. I went as far as tried to see if there's anything mixed up in the registry and here's what I got:

[image]

Comment: Set it to launch with IE.

Comment: @chipperyman573: They are launched with IE. Interestingly enough if I set them to launch with `Chrome` the icons start looking like Chrome icon, but when I switch them back to IE they get this blank look again...

Comment: use **%ProgramFiles%\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe,-17** as DefaultIcon

Comment: @magicandre1981: Thanks. Tried that and also `"%ProgramFiles%\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe",-17` and then tried logging out and back in and that didn't change it.

Comment: clear the IconCache of Windows.

Comment: Just did. Still nothing.

Comment: Is it happening on `.htm` files only or does it also happen on `.html` files?

Comment: @Raystafarian: It happens for both `.htm` and `.html` files.

Comment: Do you get the same issue with other user accounts?

Comment: @and31415: I don't have other user accounts.